# Passing array of objects through to a child components but TS is not happy with types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi All I am trying to type a array of object which i am passing through as props.

data.json:

```
[
  {
    "category": "Reaction",
    "score": 80,
    "icon": "../../../assets/images/icon-reaction.svg"
  },
  {
    "category": "Memory",
    "score": 92,
    "icon": "../../../assets/images/icon-memory.svg"
  },
]
```

I Import this data to App component and pass it down as a prop to its child component `UserSkillResult`:

```
    import React, { FC } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserSkillResult from './UserSkillResult/UserSkillResult';
import scoreData from '../data/data.json';

const App: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  // console.log('APP', scoreData);
  return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <UserSkillResult scoreData={scoreData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In the child component i am trying to type this prop like this:

```
type SkillType = {
  category: string;
  score: number;
  icon: string;
};

type UserSkillResultType = SkillType[];

export const UserSkillResult: FC<UserSkillResultType> = ({
  scoreData,
}): JSX.Element => return what ever
```

The error i am getting is this:

```
Property 'scoreData' does not exist on type 'UserSkillResultType'.ts(2339)
```

I am confused because `scoreData` is not a key on the `data.json` its juts a prop name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your component as `FC<{ scoreData: UserSkillResultType[] }>` or define a type with `type ExampleProps = { scoreData: UserSkillResultType[] }` and use that. Basically the type that you want is not structured correctly.

If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Hi @Lars Vonk thank you for your answer that works i gone with the second option, but it is still bothering  me why a prop name has to be part of a type

Comment: It is because it is an object, so it should match the type of an object with that Property name but you can also use `[key: string]` to make it variable